# Relationship between power spectra, density perturbations and temperature?

Tags: perturbation-theory, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

I am trying to understand how density perturbations relate to temperature fluctuations in the CMB. I understand the physical effects involved, but my question is how is the density power spectrum related to the temperature power spectrum?